# Theory of Computation can't design a DFA

Tags: computation-theory, dfa

hello guys can you help me with this question i can't solve it on my own 
consider a language over the alphabet Σ={a,b,c} with all strings  with a's never preceded by b's and never followed by c's . Design and implement a DFA that would accept this language?

thank you :)

Comment: It seems that you are asking us to do your homework.

Comment: it is not a homework it is a part of documentation for my final project and i cant solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the questions, you want a dfa that ended with c,a,b? Or a dfa that ended with, for example only a is correct?
For the first example, the dfa is like:

1. q0 -> initial state
2. from q0 to q1 with c
3. from q1 to q1 with c
4. from q1 to q2 with a
5. from q1 to q0 with b
6. from q2 to q2 with a
7. from q2 to q3 with b
8. q3 --> final state
9. from q3 to q3 with b.

Comment: a DFA that accepts all strings with a's never preceded by b's and never followed by c's

Comment: ok but only a, is accepted or not? or cccccaaaaaabb is accepted?

Comment: cccccaaaaaabb is accepted too all strings that starts with C and ends with B are accepted and after that i have to write a code to describe this DFA

Comment: you must be more specific. 
only a is accepted? cabcab is accepted? acbcab is accepted?

Comment: If you want a dfa that accepted only c^n a^n b^n with n>=1 is the dfa that I have wrote.

Comment: i solve it Liz thank you could not have done it with out you :)

Answer (score 0):

Input alphabets  Σ={a,b,c}

Given language a's never preceeded by b's and never followed by c's

The strings present in this language are
L={a,b,c,aa,bb,cc,ab,bc,abc,bca,bcaa,...}

```
DFA for given language is
    The transitions are as follows:
           (q0,a)=q0
           (q0,b)=q1
           (q0,c)=q2
           (q1,a)=q4
           (q1,b)=q1
           (q1,c)=q2
           (q2,a)=q3
           (q2,b)=q1
           (q2,c)=q2
           (q3,a)=q3
           (q3,b)=q1
           (q3,c)=q4
           (q4,a)=q4
           (q4,b)=q4
           (q4,c)=q4
```

where q0,q1,q2,q3 are final states and q4 is dead state.

From the above transitions we can clearly say that the language can contain only a's ,a's preceeded by c's, a's followed by b's ....

If a's are preceeded by b's and followed by c's then the transition goes to dead state q4....

Image for above DFA:

[DFA Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmm5h.jpg)

Hope u got it.!!